# Merging a Bottom Nav bar with other code in Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin

I'm building an app with multiple people right now and I'm trying to merge the bottom navigation bar I made with someone else's code - but the app crashes immediately due to a runtime error after I implemented my navigation bar with this really long message. Anyone know how to fix this?

```
2020-06-30 00:59:26.429 7505-7505/com.example.unieats E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.unieats, PID: 7505
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.unieats/com.example.unieats.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar.setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3430)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3614)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:86)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2199)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:112)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar.setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at androidx.navigation.ui.ActionBarOnDestinationChangedListener.setTitle(ActionBarOnDestinationChangedListener.java:48)
        at androidx.navigation.ui.AbstractAppBarOnDestinationChangedListener.onDestinationChanged(AbstractAppBarOnDestinationChangedListener.java:103)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.addOnDestinationChangedListener(NavController.java:233)
        at androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(NavigationUI.java:227)
        at androidx.navigation.ui.ActivityKt.setupActionBarWithNavController(Activity.kt:74)
        at com.example.unieats.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:27)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7458)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7448)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1286)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3614) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:86) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2199) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:112) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987)
```

Update: it seems like my MainActivity file is the one causing the problems. Below this is the code for that file - everything before val navView is code that already existed, and everything after is what I added.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val navView: BottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)

        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(
            R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_search, R.id.navigation_log,
            R.id.navigation_settings, R.id.navigation_profile))
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        navView.setupWithNavController(navController) 
         
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you share the code before before val navView i think there is something wrong there
or check your AppTheme in your res/values/style.xml
if your AppTheme parent ends with .NoActionBar if so change it to .DarkActionBar
Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

The error doesn't seem to be coming from the navigation bar that you are merging, but instead from the ActionBar. Make sure you have the action bar you are calling in the activity/fragment created so that you can set the title to it, as the error indicates.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response! I'm just wondering what you mean by having an action bar in the activity/fragment - as in the MainActivity file? I'm not declaring an action bar in MainActivity as of right now, but I'm using the setupActionBarWithNavController command. Is that the issue you mean? (sorry I have no prior experience with Android studio)

Comment: I think without seeing the code where the issue is being run into, it's hard for me to tell

Comment: Updated the original post - if you could take a look that'd be greatly appreciated :)
Thanks!